# How to build an .exe out of a React Native for Windows project

Tags: react-native, build, react-native-windows

Im creating a desktop app with React Native for Windows and now Im wondering how can I export or build my project to a .exe-file.

Comment: [Callstack Blog | How to Build a Desktop App with React Native for Windows](https://callstack.com/blog/how-to-build-a-desktop-app-with-react-native-for-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can build an .exe. Here are the documented distribution methods:
https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/0.64/native-code#distribution